# SelectList onchange not firing only for some values

Tags: visualforce, selectlist, onchange

Having a simple `apex:selectList` and using `apex:actionSupport` to handle user selections which is working fine. Surprised that the event is not firing **only for some values**.

page:

```
<apex:actionRegion id="salesItemActionRegion">
       <apex:outputLabel value="Sales Item : "></apex:outputLabel>
       <apex:selectList id="drpSalesItem" value="{!selectedProduct}" size="1">
           <apex:selectOptions id="optnSalesItem" value="{!ProductList}"></apex:selectOptions>
           <apex:actionSupport rerender="pnlProductInfo" action="{!LoadProductDetails}" event="onchange" />
       </apex:selectList>                            
</apex:actionRegion>
```

Controller:

```
//action fires from prduct drop down on change
    public void LoadProductDetails(){
        SalesItemWrapper wrapper = new SalesItemWrapper();  //reset wrapper
        selectedProductWrapper = new List<SalesItemWrapper>();
        System.debug('selected:'+selectedProduct);
        System.debug('choices:' + productList);
        if(!productList.isEmpty() && productList.size() >1){
            if(selectedProduct != null && !selectedProduct.equalsIgnoreCase(MENU_SELECT_ID)){
                String[] keyArr = selectedProduct.split('-');
                wrapper.salesItemId = (keyArr != null)?keyArr[0] : '';  //tracking related sales_item__c(product) id for future reference
                wrapper.salesItemName = (keyArr != null)?keyArr[1] : ' ';
                wrapper.salesItemCode = (keyArr != null)?keyArr[2] : ' ';
                selectedProductWrapper.add(wrapper);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'll add the here a `selectOption` that's not firing the `onchange` event.

```
System.SelectOption[value="a0h90000002KMnDAAW-103 PW-Legionella spp  Plate Count (YEA) - Potable Water", label="103 PW - Legionella spp  Plate Count (YEA) - Potable Water", disabled="false"]
```

Tried to use `apex:outputLabel` with `selectedProduct` to check what it shows. Still no value or having previous value if any;not changing the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with the value of `selectOption`. In between the value, there are **double sapces** which caused to fail some salesforce validations.

In the value `Legionella spp  Plate Count (YEA)` replaced the double space between *spp* and *Plate* with a single space and it's working fine.

As per my understanding this happens due to the way that salesforce perform server side validation for `selectOption`. When we select a value they forcefully replace multiple spaces with a single space and at the validation it's not get match;onchange will not fire. Any explanation about this is highly appreciated and I'll keep this answer until then so that someone get a help.

**Thing to learn** : Even you 110% confident with your code, have some `<apex:pageMessages />`inside a rerendering component. Because you can't guess when a server side validation will fail and break your code blindly, if you are not an expert :)